# JCombobox's popup list is not painted completely

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, paint, jinternalframe

I have a `JInternalFrame` in a `JDesktop`, and I also have a `JComboBox` in the internal frame. The problem is shown below.

[image: problem]

How can I make `JComboBox` paint outside `JInternalFrame`, so that the popup list can be shown completely? Is using glass pane an *optimal solution*, or would it be *bad practice*?

---

**SOLUTION:**
I have found the solution; just override the `getSize()` method of `JComboBox`:

```
class MyComboBox extends JComboBox{

    public Dimension getSize(){
        return new Dimension(..);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try calling `setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false)` on the JCombobox before attempting anything with the glass pane.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work.. I am using it as follows:


    class MyComboBox extends JComboBox{
        public MyComboBox(){
            setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);
        }
    }